# How to load a .js file in another folder with Express JS and render it?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I have a root directory containing two folders, that all have more folders within, I'm trying to reach the specified file and render it:

1. frontpage [FOLDER]

   ```
    - server.js
   ```
2. login_register [FOLDER]

   ```
   routes [Folder]
   - index.js
   - users.js
   views
   - movie_main_page.ejs
   ```

How can I take a file (server.js) from frontpage folder and use it in the login_register folder? I'm also trying to render this file as it will now serve as the main page instead of the dummy landing page after logging in (movie_main_page.ejs).

This is the code I use for rendering the landing page:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Main page of login/register
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('welcome'));

//Main page of movie site goes here
router.get('/movie_main_page', (req, res) => res.render('movie_main_page'));

module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/movie_main_page'
    })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I haven't posted the full code from the files because the system works, it renders the movie_main_page fine after logging in, but how can I render another file now that the dummy one works?

Thanks!

Comment: if your config setup is proper, then all EJS views can be in folder and all js can be imported using relative path tecnique `require('../<folder>/<file>.js')` so you can use `..` and `../../` and so on

Comment: So, I have a index.js file, can I use require() there to get the file I want and then render it there?

Comment: you define router.post anywhere you want and render anywhere you want, you can require anything anywhere